# FileUpload in ASP.NET, what is the path of the uploaded file.

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem in uploading a file in ASP.NET web application. I am not able to get the correct physical path of a file in hard drive.

I have tried using `Server.Mappath(fileupload.postedfile.filename)` and `path.GetFullPath(fileupload.postedfile.filename)`.

Both are pointing the wrong path. How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Hello, can you please share the code of your upload process? also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and make sure you have the minimum required in your question.

Comment: .NET doesn't automatically upload a file to disk for you. So you wont be able to find it using the name (unless you've written it there yourself). Assuming its an ```FileUploadControl``` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.110).aspx)) you can use the ```fileupload.PostedFile.InputStream``` ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx)) to access the contents of the file.

Comment: I tried to save the file using FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));

Answer (score 2):

Try using below code .

`Server.MapPath("~/Files")` returns an absolute path based on a folder relative to your application

```
protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string folderPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/");

    //Check whether Directory (Folder) exists.
    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        //If Directory (Folder) does not exists. Create it.
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
    }

    //Save the File to the Directory (Folder).
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(folderPath + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName));

    //Display the success message.
    lblMessage.Text = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName) + " has been uploaded.";
}
```

Check is performed whether the Folder (Directory) exists. If it does not then the Folder (Directory) is created.

Then the uploaded File is saved into the Folder (Directory).

Comment: i have tried this.i got this error message "Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\filenamel' is denied".

Comment: 1.check the rights to folder may be you will have read-only rights to folder ,remove that . run Visual Studio as Administrator.(R-Click-> Run as Administrator). it might help you .

Answer (score 0):

You get the uploaded file as a Stream on the server. you should save it on the disk and then use it (or use the Stream directly).